# Android Home button Long press

Tags: android, kiosk

I am working on kiosk APP in android like [**SureLock**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gears42.surelock), i am facing the problem to handle the android home button long press event. Please suggest me how to handle Home button long press event.

Answer (score 1):

Use the code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810038/how-to-catch-the-home-button-click-in-android) answer to capture the home button key down event, and in `onKeyUp` subtract the times between the events and decide whether it is a long press or not (1 second, I'd say?)