# how to disable home button in android?

Tags: android

i want to disable android device `home button` when my app runs.

i have tried following code but it din't help :

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the home button!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

     @Override
     protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
     super.onNewIntent(intent);
     if (Intent.ACTION_MAIN.equals(intent.getAction())) {
     Log.i("MyLauncher", "onNewIntent: HOME Key");

     }
     }
```

Comment: Simply say, you can't !!!

Comment: Yes! agreed with @ManishAndroid.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable Home button in Android 4.0 or above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13560100/disable-home-button-in-android-4-0-or-above)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162182/android-is-it-possible-to-disable-the-click-of-home-button

Comment: you can : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10810075/1168654

Comment: You Can't Disable Home Button Just Override It....

Comment: @ManishDubey really ? than how does Mcfee wave secure does it ? or Lookout and many others ?

Comment: do u want to hide navigation button?

Comment: You can check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20945431/1557187

Answer (score 16):

I think this can be done in another style if suits your requirement. By creating your activity as home activity. If you want to disable home button and show your custom application activity as launcher when home button is pressed. Just add these lines in manifest for that activity for which you want your launcher.

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.TempActivity"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true" >
             <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

After adding and run your application. if user presses the home button, Android will ask for which launcher you want your home. Then your have to select your application launcher ALWAYS not ONLY ONCE.

if you want fully disable the user, so that he cant move to another screen then set theme to fullscreen with NoTitlebar.

Comment: ... and than your app gets started everytime the users presses the home button ... usually not what you want to archive

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Android-HomeKey-Locker](https://github.com/shaobin0604/Android-HomeKey-Locker) to disable HOME KEY and other system keys(such as BACK KEY and MENU KEY)

**NOTE**

It seems that the solution only works on devices with hard home key

Hope this will help you in your application. Thanks.

Comment: @menu_on_top clone the repo, add HomeLockerLib to your app project's dependancies

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your solution, but is it possible for soft home keys also? Please suggest some idea if it is possible.

Comment: I installed a "Button Locker" app from the Playstore. I don't know if it is the same app you are talking about. It works. It locks the defective home button of my phone. But the app is useless because it has a side effect which makes it unusable. It disables the softkeyboard which does not appear anymore when I want to type in Whatsapp.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot disable home button.

There is no way to intercept the home button on Android, unless you make your app the home screen. This is for security reasons, so that malicious apps cannot take over your device by overriding all the buttons that can exit.

Home button is one sure short way to navigate to home screen.

If you want to handle the HOME button, implement a home screen.

[Not able disable Home button on specific android devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349685/not-able-disable-home-button-on-specific-android-devices)

Check the answer by commonsware

Comment: :D I am asking about the question (too many questions are there). Not saying that your answer is duplicate :)

Comment: duplicate of question already exist on SO with same topic. Don't increase you number of answers with some links copied from another answer suggested for same topic on SO.

Comment: @Raghunandan : You should give comment with hyperlink on Commonsware answer instead of post new answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below method to disable the Home key in android:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything.. what is supposed to happen exactly?