# how to disable home button when toggle button clicked

Tags: android

i want to disable navigation bar in my app.i have use below code for it.it disable back button.now i want to disable home button when click on toggle button.how to disable home button using toggle button

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK ) {
            //preventing default implementation previous to 
            //android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
            return false;
        }     
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);    
    }
```

Comment: I don't think the home button can be disabled, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183905/how-to-disable-home-button-in-android/17183967#17183967.

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable the home button.

But there is a workaround: Start your app again as soon as another app is launched.
See http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/