# Bring app to forefront and "lock"?

Tags: android

Are there any limitations (either technical or "rules") that would prevent me from creating an Android app that essentially:
at a given interval comes to the forefront (becomes the "active" app).
will not let the user do anything else (change apps, etc.) until they succesfully perform an action within the app.

If so, and you're able to point me to documentation, I'd be grateful.

Thank you!

Comment: You tagged this android but asked about iOS.  One of these is wrong, which one?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I meant Andriod!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, you cannot simply disable the android home button or menu button but if you can have a look in the URL

[how to disable home button in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183905/how-to-disable-home-button-in-android)

and find anything helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

None of the app can do this, the user can select the Home button and select between different apps he can work upon. On that note you can only unlock the phone and not even lock an iPhone or iPad

Refer

[Programmatically lock and unlock iPhone screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832940/programmatically-lock-and-unlock-iphone-screen)

Comment: Good answer. Sorry, I actually meant Android though. I've edited above.

Comment: Welcome mate, i dont have that good knowledge of android. But let me check what i can find for you.

As far as i know you can disable back button in android but, home button or menu button cannot be disabled