# Can I disable home button On Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I can not disable home button and Which is next to it in android I tried this code but does not work

```
 @Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
}
```

Do you have any idea for solve this problem?
Or Can I hide navigation bar permanently forever؟

Comment: you want to hide the navigation bar permanently forever!? why would you want to do such a thing? you could go fullscreen and hide it while in fullscreen

Comment: You can't in Android disable or completly hide the navigation bar. But you can set your app as kind of launcher, for example in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27120660/5508719

Comment: Beware that not allowing your users quit your app may make them a bit angry with you.

Comment: there should be no way to do that.

Comment: @JulianSchmuckli thanks you saved my day

Comment: for those who claim that this shouldn't be allowed at all: think of kiosk-applications. If you put a tablet in a shop for example - maybe for checking a price of an item via a barcode-scanner, your don't want your customers to terminate the app and have access to the underlying operating system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it.
I took a part from here 
[how to disable home button in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183905/how-to-disable-home-button-in-android/27120660#27120660)
and added one row Which originally existed
LAUNCHER row as follow:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 4):

> Can I hide navigation bar permanently forever?

No, system would not allow you to do so. But you can prevent the app from exiting. 
Do the following in your onPause() method.

```
 @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        activityManager.moveTaskToFront(getTaskId(), 0);
    }
```

You need the following permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
```

Comment: Thanks,
but does not work .
Do I need for any permission?

Comment: It is good thing but only works for the square button and for home button does not work