# Stay on current activity on home button click

Tags: android, android-homebutton

Looking around I found many Q&A about how to (try) override the home button click and how to kiosk the user into an app. Many were confusing, many not working and many really long and complex to implement.

That said, what I would like to achieve is to keep current activity on "`home button click`".

Setting the app as `default launcher`, I succesfully close the user into my app, but the problem is that the user can go to the main activity clicking the `home button`, canceling any in-progress workflow.

Example, I have `Activity 1`, `Activity 2` and `Activity 3`.

From `Activity 1` user can go to `Activity 2` and from `Activity 2` he can go to `Activity 3`.

Going back from 3 to 2 and from 2 to 1, causes some workflows to run and things to appens.

What I want is that if the user clicks the `home button` from `Activity 1`, he stays on `Activity 1`, if he clicks it from `Activity 2` he stays on `Activity 2` and if he clicks it on `Activity 3`, he stays on `Activity 3`.

Is there a way to accomplish this goal? I've been struggling on it really a while.

PS: clicking "`home`" from `Activity 3` must **not** destroy `Activity 1` and 2 since I need to wait for the `ActivityResult` of 3 and 2.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44544167/can-i-disable-home-button-on-android) is maybe helpfull

Comment: I think this will help you: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity. It would be helpful if you provided some code.