# Block one time bottom navigation buttons: system and physical

Tags: java, android, android-navigation, android-homebutton, android-recents

I need something to block "Recent apps" and "Home" buttons, but I don't need to block them completely, only to prevent an accidental exit from the application. Most often you could see a toast with a message "Click again to exit the app" in this case, so I want something similar. 
So for "Back" button it will be really easy to do, but for others it's not.

I found [this link](https://hackernoon.com/disable-android-home-back-and-active-apps-buttons-f7450dfeddcd). But my phone creates strange bottom chooser dialog, when I click "Home" button, and I am not sure, that I can undo this actions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to disable home button in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183905/how-to-disable-home-button-in-android)

Comment: @M. Prokhorov no. I tried everything that suggested there, but making my activity HOME, creates strange dialog, and the answer that it is not possible isn't quite right. Because you can see the toast that I mention in my question inside fullscreen games for example.

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to "create strange dialog". Android doesn't allow complete override of the home button, user will still have a deal of control, i.e. which of the installed apps that provide a "home" screen he wants to go to when the button is pressed.

Comment: @M. Prokhorov yes, but somehow apps control this buttons without any system dialogs.

Comment: Which apps? I haven't seen this anywhere.

Comment: M. Prokhorov for example https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.king.candycrushsaga

Comment: It doesn't intercept home button from what I can tell - only the "back".

Comment: @ M. Prokhorov maybe it has different behavior on different phones, in my case it intercept all buttons that can close the app