# How to disable device home button in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-homebutton

I want to disable device home button when my app run or my screen display
Check the attached video link.
[Reference video, that is what i want](https://imgur.com/53xcCYt)

Thanks

I wrote simple code in which my activity overrides the

```
onKeyDown()
```

and return true for all key presses.
Does any one have any idea?

Comment: You want to disable it for the entire device?

Comment: Yes, look the video link i want exactly same

Comment: This app seems to do it, although it apparently makes the keyboard not show up https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pandaz.app.button.locker and its also not updated since long ago. Also see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183905/how-to-disable-home-button-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Use `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)` to remove the home button from the action bar.

Comment: Nothing happened..